# when scrooge-mcetherface install in ubuntu, i got much more error,

Tags: scrooge

i try to install scrooge-mcetherface, but i got more error, i also install latest mythril version and all require file but when i runing main directory ./scrooge (address) i got error

````
  File "/home/vip72/scrooge-mcetherface/./scrooge", line 7, in <module>
    from scmf.raid import Raid
  File "/home/vip72/scrooge-mcetherface/scmf/raid.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .helper import W3
  File "/home/vip72/scrooge-mcetherface/scmf/helper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from web3.utils.empty import empty
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3.utils'   ```
````

Comment: Install these and check if works.  sudo apt-get install python-dev 
sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev

Comment: i am using  virtual environment, can i install these package without removing the virtual environment? also python-dev not found, maybe u meant python3-dev right?

Comment: yes please you can run apt-get install python3-dev -y

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vip72/scrooge-mcetherface/./scrooge", line 7, in <module>
    from scmf.raid import Raid
  File "/home/vip72/scrooge-mcetherface/scmf/raid.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .helper import W3
  File "/home/vip72/scrooge-mcetherface/scmf/helper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from web3.utils.empty import empty
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3.utils'`

Comment: again got error, not change anything

Comment: you using scrooge-mcetherface? pls telegram write me @joincentric

Answer (score 0):

Edited : if you have pip installed install web3 from pip . pip install web3.

I will ping you through telegram after few hours

Comment: thank u i will waiting you in telegram

Comment: pls can u write me in telegram??

Comment: still not solve

Comment: can u guide me? still waiting u